# PHP concated string is blank at the end

Tags: php, string, loops

I am trying to concatenate a string in a loop and when its is over the string is blank (or whatever value it was before). I am not exactly sure what is happening but I can't seem to find a similar issue.

```
$toItem = "";
$recpItem = "";

if(is_array($to))
{
    foreach($to as $key=>$email)
    {
        $recpItem = $recpItem.'<item><recip dn="'.$email.'" sa="'.$email.'" ra="'.$email.'" al="" rt="SMTP" id="" ao="3" rf="0" ei="0" uri=""/></item>';
        $email = htmlentities($email);
        $toItem = $toItem.'<item><Rcp DN="'.$email.'" EM="'.$email.'" RT="SMTP" AO="3"/></item>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `$to` is an array that has data in it?

Comment: What does `var_dump($to)` output?

Comment: Sidenote: I noticed you have both `rt="SMTP"` and `RT="SMTP"` --- On a UNIX/LINUX server, `RT != rt` and vice-versa. Meaning, that lettercase is sensitive. As is `DN` and `dn` etc.

Comment: @newfurniturey and Mike I have done var_dump and it is outputting correctly as an array.

Fred you have a keen eye, this is correct and it is an case sensitive request. However it is a Windows server, which I my self find it odd that is it so case sensitive. If you are wondering, this is part of a post request to a OWA (Outlook Web Access) server.

Comment: That's why I mentioned Unix/Linux ;) I know that it doesn't matter on a Windows server. Cheers @kendall15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add the code to an array then `implode()` it:

```
$to = array(
  'bob@gmail.com',
  'sally@gmail.com'
);

if(is_array($to)){
  $recpItem = array();
  $toItem = array();

  foreach($to as $email){
     $recpItem[] = '<item><recip dn="'.$email.'" sa="'.$email.'" ra="'.$email.'" al="" rt="SMTP" id="" ao="3" rf="0" ei="0" uri=""/></item>';
     $email = htmlentities($email);
     $toItem[] = '<item><Rcp DN="'.$email.'" EM="'.$email.'" RT="SMTP" AO="3"/></item>';
  }

  $recpHtml = implode($recpItem);
  $toHtml = implode($toItem);

  echo $recpHtml;
  echo '<hr />';
  echo $toHtml;

}
```

Comment: I believe this will work but I will have to try it later. Thanks.

Comment: I tested it here and it works : http://www.compileonline.com/execute_php_online.php